# If "External secrets are not available to containers created by docker-compose", what's the recommended way to build them?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I run

```
docker-compose build && docker stack deploy -c docker-compose yml somestack
```

it builds fine and the secrets seem to be readable, but the build issues warnings like:

```
WARNING: Service "foo" uses secret "foo_pw" which is external. External secrets are not available to containers created by docker-compose.
```

Am I doing it wrong? What should I be running instead of `docker-compose build`?

Comment: You can build images without docker compose. It's just a `docker build ...` command.

Comment: @BMitch is there a short form that builds the containers listed in the compose file, rather than having to list them individually?

Comment: You can make a small build script. It's one line of script vs one line of a compose file.

Comment: Is that the recommended way? Do you mean that `docker compose` simply does not support that, and we *must* do without it?